# Do I need a USRP2 block in GRC in order to use the USRP2 hardware?

Tags: data-transfer, gnuradio, transmitfile, usrp

I am trying to find the USRP2 blocks in order to utilize my USRP2. In alot of examples their exists a USRP2 Source that they use and maybe thats the reason why I'm not able to actually send and receive a signal using two USRP2's. We turn on the receiver at exactly the same freq as the transmitter and we are never capable of seeing a signal. The root of this question lies in that if we do the same thing but with 2 URSP1's we can see something in the receiver side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'USRP2' blocks are deprecated, and should no longer be used.  GNURadio now uses the 'UHD' block for all USRP devices.  Put a UHD block into your flowgraph, and you should have more luck.  If you see a non-UHD block being used for a USRP in an example, that just means the example is out of date.